# Windows explorer key to jump to end of selection

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

When renaming a file (`example.txt`) in the windows explorer, the name (`example`.txt) will be highlighted and gets replaced when typing. When pressing the right arrow key, the selection clears and the caret moves to after the point (`example.|txt`). When pressing the left arrow key, the selection clears and the caret moves one to the left (`exampl|e.txt`). Which key do I have to press that the selection clears but the caret stays at the end of the selection (`example|.txt`)?

Comment: If purpose is known, better solutions can be suggested.. btw, is it okay if it is achieved by two key press in sequence?

Comment: There is no special purpose, I'm just curious if there is such key. I just could press left then right, but that's cheating :D

Comment: you can change under folder options "Hide extensions for known file types" so the .txt will not be showed any more

Comment: @emirjonb what if the extension is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you **should** be able to simply press the <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> or the <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to do this but, unfortunately, Explorer is broken for the most part. This only works correctly in a few of the view modes. In the following picture, everything with a red line under it is broken and will treat these as the <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> respectively.

[image]

Comment: Nice detective work ;) You should probably delete your other answer ...

Answer (score 0):

`Shift-insert` will position the cursor where you want it.  Note however, that the clipboard **must** be empty or this key combination will paste text from the clipboard.

Comment: No it won't. It will paste the contents of the clipboard.

Comment: Will it not replace the filename by the clipboard contents?

Comment: @DavidPostill & Win8_learner - It will work if there's nothing in the clipboard.

Comment: Most users having something on the clipboard.

Comment: That's not the context of this question, and, you can't make that assumption.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your answer to say "Shift-insert will position the cursor where you want it (as long as the clipboard is empty). Then the answer is both complete and correct.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the suggestion.  I've made the appropriate update.